# Ubuntu 20.04 : continious screen flicker after return from supend ( *ERROR* CPU pipe A FIFO underrun )

Tags: 20.04, suspend, intel-graphics, display-resolution, flicker

After return from suspend the screen of my laptop flickers. You can't continue work with that.
In kernel log you see :

```
[drm:intel_cpu_fifo_underrun_irq_handler [i915]] *ERROR* CPU pipe A FIFO underrun
```

So I played with display settings. Changing the refresh rate doesn't help, but lower the resolution (from 1920x1080). So in any lower resolution I don't have a problem. But of course I have to loose a lot of pixels when using a default resolution. So I decided to add my own 1912x1080. For some strange reason this is enough to avoid flickering.

So I added this lines to my ~./profile:

```
xrandr --newmode "1912x1080_60.00"  171.25  1912 2032 2232 2552  1080 1083 1093 1120 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode eDP-1 "1912x1080_60.00"
```

and select this resolution.
The issue is gone but I am really wondering what is root cause of this?

My system is a Skylake core-m5-6Y54 system, running Ubuntu Mate 20.04.

Answer (score 1):

> I was able to prevent this from happening by disabling C-States in my laptop's firmware configuration ("BIOS"). For reference, it's a Dell Latitude 5490.

[Source of the solution, click here.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/588457/drmintel-cpu-fifo-underrun-irq-handler-i915-error-cpu-pipe-a-fifo-underru)
I had same problem.

Comment: I think disable C-states is a not a perfect idea for laptops (if they run on battery). But maybe this is a solution for others. I would like to know: Are you suffered from screen tearing too?

Comment: I agree but I don't find better solution yet, I tried some other driver but those don't solve that, yes my screen also had same problems. May open a ticket at the Ubuntu issue system would by better.

Comment: There is a ticket already. Maybe you can join there - not to be alone ;) https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1872760